# Recovering XMR by verifying data

Tags: monerod

Is there any way to recover monero that just disapeared from your account by verifiying it being sent from another address?

Comment: Are you seeing a zaero balance and just assuming it has been stolen or something else. Because if the former, there are several [questions and answers](https://monero.stackexchange.com/search?q=Balance+0) to fix missing balance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to get your monero back once it is sent unless the person with the monero sends it back to you.